# Merge two data frames with taking max of two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have two dataframes with the same form:

```
> df1
Day ItemId Quantity
  1      1        2
  1      2        3
  1      4        5

> df2
Day ItemId Quantity
  1      1        0
  1      2        0
  1      3        0
  1      4        0
```

I'd like to merge df1 and df2 and if a row of `['Day','ItemId']` exists in both df1 and df2 take df1 which the max
I tried this command :

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby(level=0).max(df1['Quantity'],df2['Quantity'])
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `groupby` by both columns in list and aggregate `max`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby(['Day','ItemId'], as_index=False)['Quantity'].max()
print (df)
   Day  ItemId  Quantity
0    1       1         2
1    1       2         3
2    1       3         0
3    1       4         5
```

If possible multiple columns:

```
df = (pd.concat([df1, df2])
        .sort_values(['Day','ItemId','Quantity'], ascending=[True, True, False])
        .drop_duplicates(['Day','ItemId']))
print (df)

   Day  ItemId  Quantity
0    1       1         2
1    1       2         3
2    1       3         0
2    1       4         5
```

Comment: @Dr.know - Can you explain more?